# squashed then re-squashed give different size?

Tags: embedded, firmware, root-filesystem, header-file

I extracted a  `firmware.bin` using fmk mod kit and gave me 3 files: `header.img , rootfs.img and footer.img` now whenever I cat and repack all the files together in `firmware2.bin` again, it works and it upgrades the router. but when I unsquash the `rootfs.img` using this command `unsquashfs rootfs.img` into `squashfs-root/` then I squash it again using `mksquashfs rootfs-root/ squash_new.img -comp lzma -b 131072` "which it by the way the same compression method and block size as the original `rootfs.img`" but it gives me a less size comparing to the `rootfs.img` and the router gives me upgrade failed

here are the sizes of the 2 files

> squash_new.img (9,945,088 bytes)
>
> rootfs.img (9,945,232 bytes)

is there a problem with `unsquashfs` or `mksquashfs`?

because when I used a hex editor software, I noticed some entries are different although I have not changed anything.

**EDIT** someone suggested that the `header.img` file could contain the information about the `rootfs.img` file and any change could cause an upgrade failed issue unless I match it with the info inside the `header.img` , how would I edit the `header.img` file, I can't unsquash it, only view it as hex and all the text inside is rubbish.

Comment: Just looking at the manual pages, are there any differences between the output of `unsquashfs -s squash_new.img` and `unsquashfs -s rootfs.img`? There are a number of flags that mksquashfs can take which might fix the differences.

Comment: only this
`squash_new.img Filesystem size 9941124 bytes (9708.13 Kbytes / 9.48 Mbytes)`
while
`rootfs.img Filesystem size 9941248 bytes (9708.25 Kbytes / 9.48 Mbytes)`

same compression, same block size. same everything. but the size is different

Comment: any updates for this?